# What does it mean to use the name of a class for string interpolation?

Tags: ruby, string-interpolation

The following code is an extract from rubykoans about_classes.rb:

```
class Dog7
  def initialize(initial_name)
    @name = initial_name
  end
  def to_s
    @name
  end
end
```

I created an instance of `Dog7`:

```
fido = Dog7.new("Fido")
```

I understand the following:

```
"My dog is " + fido.to_s # => "My dog is Fido"
"My dog is #{fido.to_s}" # => "My dog is Fido"
```

I do not understand why the following interpolation makes sense and gives the same result:

```
"My dog is #{fido}" # => "My dog is Fido"
```

`fido` is not a string.

Comment: In future, consider waiting longer before selecting an answer. A quick selection can discourage other, possibly better, answers, and is not appreciated by those still working on answers. There's no rush. I suggest waiting at least a couple of hours (just don't forget). This is no reflection on @Candide's answer, which I think is quite good.

Comment: It's really unclear what you are asking. What does this have to do with using the name of a class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The statement `#{fido}` implicitly calls `fido.to_s`. That's why you get the "Fido", which is the value of `@name`.

Actually, `"My dog is #{fido.to_s}"` is redundant, because the `#{}` bit will call `to_s`.

Here is another way of formatting strings:

```
"My dog is %s" % fido
```

This is pretty much another version of the `#{}` syntax. Above, the `%s` indicates to the formatter that it needs to call `to_s` on `fido`. It would be redundant to do `"My dog is %s" % fido.to_s`, however, it would still work.

Comment: ...and of course there's `"My do is " + "Fido"` or, better, `"My do is ".concat("Fido")`