# Is #{} always equivalent to to_s?

Tags: ruby, string-interpolation

In "[What does it mean to use the name of a class for string interpolation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31521756/what-does-it-mean-to-use-the-name-of-a-class-for-string-interpolation)", Candide suggested that `#{}` inside a string implicitly calls `to_s`.
So, for instance:

```
my_array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
p my_array.to_s # => "[1, 2, 3, 4]"
p "#{my_array}" # => "[1, 2, 3, 4]"
```

However, if `to_s` for Array is redefined as shown below, I would get different results:

```
class Array
  def to_s
    self.map { |elem| elem.to_s }
  end
end

p my_array.to_s # => ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
p "#{my_array}" # => "#<Array:0x007f74924c2bc0>"
```

I suppose this happens any time and anyhow  `to_s` is overridden.

What am I supposed to do to keep the equality between `to_s` and the expression `#{}` in a string, if possible?

I came across this issue in a [RubyMonk lesson](https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/4-ruby-primer-ascent/chapters/45-more-classes/lessons/104-serializing#solution4368): what according to the lesson #`{ogres}` should return, according to my experience is something different.

Comment: to_s should return a string, your map call is returning the array

Answer (score 4):

Please take a look at the documentation for [`Object#to_s`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Object.html#method-i-to_s). It says that `to_s` should return a `String`. When you override a method, you should always honor its contract. Take a look at the documentatio for [`Array#to_s`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-i-to_s) As you can see, it *also* returns a `String`. [Note that this is true for *all* the `to_X` and the `to_XYZ` methods: they **must** *always* return an object of the corresponding class and they **must not** `raise` an `Exception` or otherwise fail.]

Your implementation of `to_s`, however, does *not* return a `String`. It returns an `Array`, thus *violating* `to_s`'s contract. Once you violate a method's contract, all bets are off. Personally, I think it would be more appropriate to `raise` a `TypeError` exception here, but Ruby is trying to be nice and returns *some* `String` instead, which (in this case) prints the class name and some unique identifier.

Here is the commit to the [RubySpec project](http://rubyspec.org/) which (implicitly) states that no `Exception` is `raise`d and explicitly states that an implementation-defined but otherwise unspecified `String` is returned: [The spec for interpolation when `Object#to_s` did not return a `String` was confusing the default representation of an arbitrary object and `Object#inspect`.](https://github.com/ruby/rubyspec/commit/787c132d3f6192d605469ec881ac528d6cf4555)

The latest version of the spec, before the project was closed looks like this [`language/string_spec.rb#L197-L208`](https://github.com/ruby/rubyspec/blob/master/language/string_spec.rb#L197-L208):

> ```
> it "uses an internal representation when #to_s doesn't return a String" do
>   obj = mock('to_s')
>   obj.stub!(:to_s).and_return(42)
>
>   # See rubyspec commit 787c132d by yugui. There is value in
>   # ensuring that this behavior works. So rather than removing
>   # this spec completely, the only thing that can be asserted
>   # is that if you interpolate an object that fails to return
>   # a String, you will still get a String and not raise an
>   # exception.
>   "#{obj}".should be_an_instance_of(String)
> end
> ```

As you can see, all that is guaranteed in this case, is that you *won't* get an `Exception`, and that you *will* get a `String`, however, it says nothing about what that `String` looks like.

Answer (score 2):

Look at what Ruby is telling you:

```
"#{my_array}" # => "#<Array:0x007f74924c2bc0>"
```

That means Ruby is seeing an array returned by your `to_s` method, not a string as Ruby expects and like it'd see if you hadn't overridden the original `Array.to_s`.

Instead use something like:

```
'[%s]' % self.map { |elem| elem.to_s }.join(', ')
```

Change your code to return a String and you'll be okay.

Consider this:

```
[].class # => Array
[].to_s.class # => String

class Array
  def to_s
    self.map { |elem| elem.to_s }
  end
end

[].to_s.class # => Array

class Array
  def to_s
    '[%s]' % self.map { |elem| elem.to_s }.join(', ')
  end
end

[].to_s.class # => String

my_array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
"#{my_array}" # => "[1, 2, 3, 4]"
```

In general practice, I'd recommend being cautious overriding core and STD-Lib classes' `to_s` as they're doing what they should. For custom classes it's a good idea to implement `to_s` mimicking the same output as the core classes. Occasionally we'll have to get fancy and offer more detailed views into what an instance of an object looks like, but that's when we override `inspect`.

Answer (score 1):

Your definition of `Array#to_s` returns an array, on which `to_s` would need to be further applied. This would result in infinite recursion. I suspect Ruby has internal implementation to cut off such infinite recursion in case of `"#{my_array}"`. For `p my_array.to_s`, `my_array.to_s` is an array, and `p` applies `Array#inspect`, which does not result in infinite recursion.